# Why redirects to pub/index.php

Tags: magento-2.1

I am new to **Magento 2**. Trying to implement new theme here -

> http://new-site21.comfortcity.com.au

and it just redirects to

> http://new-site21.comfortcity.com.au/pub/index.php/

I guess, it's production mode, How do I go to default or developer mode?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can change mode with command: php bin/magento deploy:mode:set developer

Answer (score 0):

Go in the Admin panel and set this setting on:

```
Stores > Configuration > Web > Search Engine Optimization > Use Web Server Rewrites
```

It should remove the index.php from the URL.

In terms of changing the mode you can do so from the terminal using the CLI command:

```
php bin/magento deploy:mode:set developer
php bin/magento deploy:mode:set production
```

You can see which mode is currently on using:

```
php bin/magento deploy:mode:show
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you configured your webserver properly? If it's a nginx server, you should include the nginx configuration bundled with the setup, and set `$MAGE_ROOT` to the root of Magento (not the `pub`). The nginx configuration will take care of the `pub/`-part. For example:

```
upstream fastcgi_backend {
   # use tcp connection
   server  127.0.0.1:9000;
}
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name dev.site.com;
    # Don't set to the pub/-folder:
    set $MAGE_ROOT /var/www/magento2;
    include /vagrant/magento2/nginx.conf.sample;
}
```

Don't know about apache though...